# Difference between d3.event vs d3.Event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I don't know if there is any difference between `d3.Event` and the `d3.event` which is bound to both using D3.js v3. I've read some related documents but they could't help me to figure it out!

Comment: Where does `d3.Event` come from? I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 update version 4 with .Net version 4.5.1, I installed JetBrain ReSharper component too. When I'm typing `d3` ReSharper  loading all the feathers such as `Event` and `event`and both of them will be work.

Comment: I would use only `d3.event` -- not sure what your IDE is doing there.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the the d3 source code, d3.js, only ds.event exists - used for example to handle drag events.

Event is typically the class for events, so in the developer web browser you can do the following:

```js
var event = new Event();
```

On inspection of event you'll get the following:

```js
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
path: Array[0]
returnValue: true
srcElement: null
target: null
timeStamp: 1434564146702
type: "onclick"__proto__: Event
```